# Implement C=|A-B| with inc,dec,jnz (A,B are non-negative)

Tags: assembly

This is a question I saw in an interview :

> A,B are non-negative numbers and you need to return C=|A-B| where you have only the following instructions:
>
> - INC register - adds one to register
> - DEC register - subtracts one from register
> - JNZ LABEL - jumps to label if last instruction result was not zero
>
> In addition you can use other registers that their initial value is zero.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Just decrement both in a loop until one of them gets to be zero. The other is obviously the result.

Comment: @Jester: If you're decrementing both in a loop, how do you test both before the `jnz`?

Comment: I left that as an exercise to the reader. Obviously in each loop iteration you need to decrement both, and if the first one goes to zero you need to exit the loop and decrement the other outside to compensate. Do you think this needs an answer?

Comment: @Jester: I think it's a lot more involved than a comment. I suspect you need to construct an unconditional jump by using a non-zero temporary register you alernately `inc/dec`, so `jnz` always jumps. It gets kinda complicated...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's code golf.

Comment: May I ask, out of curiosity, what kind of company was asking this interview question?

Comment: @MargaretBloom : over the years I have seen headhunters in my region who have aptitude tests ask questions very similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

Just decrement both in a loop until one of them gets to be zero. The other is obviously the result.

```
    inc a
    inc b      ; make sure input is not zero
loop:
    dec a
    jnz skip
    dec b
    mov eax, b ; return b as answer
    ret
skip:
    dec b
    jnz loop
    mov eax, a ; return a as answer
    ret
```

Comment: Huh, interesting. And, come to think of it, you obviously can't avoid some other instructions (`ret`), so that would do it...

Comment: Does this handle the case where one, or both, of A or B is zero?

Comment: Good point, I somehow misunderstood the "none negative" as positive, duh.

Comment: Actually I think it still works, if very slowly. It will spin 2^32 times until it wraps around back to zero. Obviously not something you want in real code, but should work for this made-up assignment.

Comment: Even for A = 0, B = 1?

Answer (score 2):

A solution with just the instructions allowed **may be** this (though not elegant). 
Where the pseudo registers *a* and *b* holds the operands and the pseudo register *c* the result (which is initially zero as stated).

```
_dec_a:
 dec a
 inc a
jnz _dec_b

;a is zero here

  _a_zero_dec_b:
   dec b
   inc b
  jnz _a_zero_b_non_zero

;a and b are zero here 

   ;;C is the result
   inc c
   jnz _result

 _a_zero_b_non_zero:
   dec b
   inc c
 jnz _a_zero_dec_b

   ;CANNOT FALL HERE

_dec_b:
 dec b
 inc b
jnz _subtract

;b is zero here

 _b_zero_dec_a:
  dec a
  inc a
 jnz _b_zero_a_non_zero

;a and b are zero here

  ;; C is the result
  inc c
  jnz _result

 _b_zero_a_non_zero:
  dec a
  inc c
 jnz _b_zero_dec_a

  ;CANNOT FALL HERE


_subtract:
 dec a
 dec b
jnz _dec_a

 ;Result
_result:
 dec c
```

Answer (score 1):

*The original question as I saw it was:*

Using jnz, inc, dec, and halt implement abs(a - b)

*My answer:*

There is no need to use the mov eax command. just store the result in the result register using the available commands.
The solution decrements both A and B until one of them zero, then it sets the value of the other to RES register and halts the program execution. (when the program is halted the result will be in RES register).

My code would look like this:

```
// define/map names to the registers
#define A   R0
#define B   R1
#define RES R2

// This solution uses the assumption that A and B are not holding init value of negative numbers values.

// clear result if not already cleared.
DEC RES; // in case it was already cleared, this step will prevent counting through all possible values.
CLEAR_RESULT:
    INC RES;
    JNZ CLEAR_RES;

INC A; // to handle a case of A is initially zero
INC B; // to handle a case of B is initially zero

DEC_A:
    DEC A;
    JNZ DEC_B;
    //Now A is zero, and the result is B-1;
SET_B_TO_RES:
    INC RES;
    DEC B;
    JNZ SET_B_TO_RES;
    DEC RES; // compensate the incr that was initially done to handle value of 0 (should only be done here...)
    HALT;

DEC_B:
    DEC B;
    JNZ DEC_A;
    //Now B is zero, and the result is A;
SET_A_TO_RES:
    INC RES;
    DEC A;
    JNZ SET_A_TO_RES;
    HALT;

// test values:
// =============
// A B
// 0 2 // A is zero
// 2 0 // B is zero
// 1 4 // A is smaller than B
// 5 2 // B is smaller than A
// 2 2 // A is equal to B
```